# Scaffold and tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession

Tags: tensorflow

I was wondering how to use the Scaffold with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession and have the graph weights initialized with specific imported values from a Numpy array. I could not find any explicit example of similar use. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are actually several way to go on doing this.

### Saving a graph checkpoint approach

- Construct your graph.
- Init all variables.
- Run a session to assign values to each variable.
- save a checkpoint to be loaded at training time.
- use the checkpoint at train time

### Using the Model Initialization and Recovery

You can see more details here: [Tensorflow Model Recovery](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/supervisor#model_initialization_and_recovery) . Basically, you can create the tf.train.Scaffold and assign the init_fn with your init function.

I only tested the first approach can share some code:

```
  with tf.Graph().as_default():

    # build the graph as it is in training
    some code...

    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():

        # Add an op to initialize the variables.
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init_op)

        #Update your graph with starting variables
        data_dict = np.load('your_pass/model.npy', encoding='latin1').item()
        #
        var = tf.get_variable(param_name)
        sess.run(var.assign(data_dict))
        print('assignment done!')

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    # Save the variables to disk.
    save_path = saver.save(sess, FLAGS.train_dir)
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```